# Error when passing an Object to a function expecting a Dictionnary?

Tags: typescript, typing

I have the code below, where I want to pass a request object to an Http Get function

Why does `get` accept the object from `helperObj` and not the interface `Req` from `helperInt`

Link to Typescript [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQI7IN4ChkHIDWEAngFzIDOYUoA5gNz6EAOc9EA-JSAK4BbAEbRmAX1y4YfEAjDAA9iGQALCABtW0AJLgAFFEyV0GAJQ4WBTmD0ByWwBpkhs+MnTZ8pao1aoAeSEAKwMjC0JiMkoaOhAmS2R2Th5kfmFRXDFzPAjrO0dnTFM3KRk5RWU8vih1aNoGJ3YoOAEqFOxkAG0SCmp6uIBdOtj6ZAAfVMERKHHkIQUFdQg4ZQm9GIZZtOnZ+cXlkFNOgeQs8MIEJSp9gDp1BXo9avVGuGbW4szJS5AaZAFSCZjJhkABec4EHqUABEMAW0IcCSSEEoAAZEWJmLg1JodPoASZPji-LobDlCFDkLD4YiIsi0RjPtjfNBAiECUVmMTWcE9OTIVEqXCFAikRwUch0ZlPkA)

```js
interface Req {
    key: string;
    page?: number;
}

function helperInt(req: Req) {
    get('', req); // ERROR
    // Argument of type 'Req' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: string | number | boolean | (string | number | boolean)[]; }'.
    // Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Req'.(2345)
}

function helperObj(req: {
    key: string;
    page?: number;
}) {
    get('', req);
}

function get(url: string, params?: { [key: string]: string | number | boolean | (string | number | boolean)[] }) {
    console.log(url, params);
}

const myReq: Req = {
    key: "foo",
    page: 0,
};

helperInt(myReq);
helperInt({
    key: "foo",
    page: 0,
});

helperObj(myReq);
helperObj({
    key: "foo",
    page: 0,
});
```

Notes:

- Both `helperInt` and `helperObj` accept both a `Req` typed object or a literal object
- The `get` function's `params` type is supposed to match Angular's `HttpParams`
- `Req` interface is used to initialise an object, alter it if needed, before passing it to the `get` function

Comment: hi, might be of interest https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/747

Comment: Not actually, in this issue they just started enforcing a return type of `void` instead of `any`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really an Angular question, it's a Typescript question.

It boils down to:

```
interface Req {
    key: string;
    page?: number;
}

// Let's make a type alias for the type `get` expects.
type MyMap = { [key: string]: string | number | boolean | (string | number | boolean)[]; }

const myReq: Req = {key: "foo",page: 0}; // this works
const x: MyMap = { key: "foo", page: 0 }; // this works too

const y: MyMap = myReq; // Type 'Req' is not assignable to type 'MyMap'. Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Req'
```

So what's the problem?

Well, if Typescript allowed this, you could do:

```
const x: Req = { key: 'foo', page: 0 };
const y: MyMap = x;
y.key = 0;
y.page = true;
console.log(x.key.toUppercase());
```

`x` has type `Req`, so static typing says `x.key.toUppercase()` is safe. But we've managed to assign a non-string to `x.key`, since `x` and `y` are references to the same object.

Therefore, Typescript disallows this.

One way to work around it is to spread the object into a new object.

```
const y: MyMap = { ...myReq };
```

Typescript can see that the object you're creating is consistent with `MyMap`, but since it's a new object subsequent changes won't break the type contract.

Comment: I see, so the solution is to destructure the object in my `helperInt` function, thanks. PS: I entered the TypeScript tag first, but Angular got listed first.